# Vim Macros: Insert Mode

Tags: vim

I am trying to create an insert macro where if I type in the command @f it should print out a for loop. I got that part working. However, I would like to leave the user in insert mode before the 1st semicolon. I tried to leave the last command before I quit the record as 'a' for append, but that did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: How about using a snippets plugin instead of macros?

Comment: I agree with @FDinoff, but if you are still curious about fixing your attempt, then please show us what you have so far.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `<C-o>q` to finish recording while in insert mode. `<C-o>` in insert mode allows you to execute one command in normal mode, and then returns to insert mode (see `:help i^O`).

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is to use abbreviations. For example:

`iabbrev  @f  for(; ; )<C-O>4<Left>`

Then in insert mode type `@f` and when you hit `Space` after it, the abrevation will be executed and you will got a `for( *; ; )`, where the `*` signs the cursor.